Excel Refresh using win32com
def excel_refresh_query_replace(path, query_list = [], old_str = '', replacement_str = '', index_update = False, max_bk_date = '', sub_list = []):

    Application = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    #Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    
    #opens the excel file
    wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(path)

    if wb.ReadOnly:
        wb.Close(False)
        try:
            os.system("taskkill /f /im  excel.exe")
            time.sleep(5)
        except:
            pass
        return True

    #if variables passed in then replace in query string
    if query_list != []:
        for query_name in query_list:
            #existing query is initialized
            current_q = wb.Queries(f"{query_name}").Formula
            #replace string requires the new string as well as the old string to be replaces
            new_q = current_q.replace(old_str,replacement_str)
            wb.Queries(f"{query_name}").Formula = new_q

    #refresh
    wb.RefreshAll()
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()

    if sub_list != []:
        for sub_name in sub_list:
            Application.Run("sub_name")

    #Updates the Index tab if required
    if index_update:
        wb.Sheets("Index").Range("E5").Value = f"Last Updated: {datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}"

        if max_bk_date != '':
            wb.Sheets("Index").Range("E6").Value = f"Last Booking Date Updated: {max_bk_date}"
    
    #Save & Close
    wb.Close(True)
    
    try:
        os.system("taskkill /f /im  excel.exe")
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        pass

    return False

This function works completely fine but due to large data, when I pass multiple queries, it doesn't refresh all the files. I loop around 500 files to refresh and around 70 files doesn't refresh fully. I get "Data not completely downloaded" issue. It refreshes completely fine when I try refresh individual query manually. Any suggestion how-to refresh queries individually.
Tried wb.Queries(f"{query_name}").Refresh() but gives out the below error
wb.Queries(query_name).Refresh() File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Refresh pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)```

ps: I am using a query connection from SQL server

